# Java Excel file read Date Column with sjxlsx

Tags: java, excel, date

I have a big excel file and I found that sjxlsx library is a good one for reading my file ( because of reading speed ).

I have one problem and can't find a fix for this. When I try to getValue() on a Cell that have Date format in Excel file a get a number on response but is not related to Date data from excel file.

In Excel file I have date in format: m/d/Y.
Doing cell.getValue() - returns a number not related to date.

How can I fix my problem ?
Is there another good java library for parsing excel files ?

Here is code that I use to read from Excel file ( I'm sure that my date column is B ):

```
 SimpleXLSXWorkbook workbook = new SimpleXLSXWorkbook(companiesFileResource.getFile());
    HSSFWorkbook hsfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet hsfSheet = hsfWorkbook.createSheet();
    com.incesoft.tools.excel.xlsx.Sheet sheetToRead = workbook.getSheet(0, false);
    com.incesoft.tools.excel.xlsx.Sheet.SheetRowReader reader = sheetToRead.newReader();

    System.out.println("Preparing to start saving data");
    com.incesoft.tools.excel.xlsx.Cell[] row;
    int rowPos = 0;
    while ((row = reader.readRow()) != null) {
        if(row[0].getValue() == null) continue;

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("m/d/Y");
        try {
            System.out.println("DATE: " + row[1].toString());
            companie.setRegisterDate(dateFormat.parse(row[1].toString()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to parse the value, it's not the formatted numeric value you see in Excel that POI reads. Use the `DateUtils`

```
if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(row[1])) {
                    System.out.println(row[1].getDateCellValue());
```

See more https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have method getDateCellValue() in sjxlsx

Comment: Bummer HSSFWorkbook led me to believe that you used POI also